# request payload versus query string parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax, payload

I am absolutely in the dark when it comes to this request payload that I'm seeing in my Chrome  browser.

A Query string will have a variable attached like session:2g0SoEE but this payload has just one long string I'm guessing is in base64.

I do understand that the request payload can have whatever, but how do I use it?

Can I do a post with jquery and send this request payload?

For example:

```
$.post(url, {variable: "variable"}, function(data){});
```

When this posts it will send &variable=variable this will be found as query string parameter in the headers sent in chrome.

In this game I'm playing I see another piece of info being sending in the header called a payload request. I'm a confused as to how this is read, used, made, how I can reduplicate this?

Here is something similar: [Chrome is caching an HTTP PUT request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753751/chrome-is-caching-an-http-put-request) 
and
[How to retrieve Request Payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597052/how-to-retrieve-request-payload)

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm not sure what you are talking about. Can you show some code? What are you trying to do, where is the data coming from?

Comment: Added more about where I'm seeing it.

Comment: Does anyone know how to send a payload request?

Comment: Yeah, so I just had to look this up.  
You send a payload request by changing the type of the ajax post to:
application/json;charset=UTF-8